# android - upload pictures to dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am new to android programming. I am trying to upload pictures to dropbox, but I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception during the photo upload.

Here is my code snippet

```
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
    String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
    System.out.println("mFile is " + file);
    System.out.println("path is  " + path);
    System.out.println("fis is " + fis);
    mRequest = mdpi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(), null);
    if (mRequest != null) {
        mRequest.upload();

    }
```

The error is pointing me to this line `mRequest = mdpi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(), null);`

When i print out the variables which I am using in this line. I am getting the image path directory successfully, but don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to declare the `mdpi` and to instanciate it.